# Opening an app from its iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

I was wondering if it is possible to launch my app from a share extension? If so, how would I do it using Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) (emphasis mine):

> A Today widget **(and no other app extension type)** can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the openURL:completionHandler: method of the NSExtensionContext class.